# Problem with script not unchecking boxes when checking another one in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to set up an onedit script for google sheet that unchecks all tickboxes in one column when a new one in the same column is ticked in.

```
 function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value == "FALSE") return;
  for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
    if(i == e.range.rowStart) continue;
// Here I am trying to check if the cell has the value TRUE and if so change it to FALSE.
    if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1).value == "TRUE"){
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
}
```

I'm going through the cells with an FOR statement and try to check if they have the value TRUE and if so change it to FALSE. It seems to not detect any TRUE though. If I remove the IF statement it does keep the newly checked box checked but fills the whole column with the FALSE value.

What is it that I am missing or have misunderstood trying to use the IF statement to detect TRUE and change it to FALSE?

Comment: if they are checkboxes, their value would be boolean. try after removing the quotes from "true", "false"

Comment: Tried to remove the quotes. Getting the same results as before.

Comment: `.value` should be changed to `.getValue()`

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve it. Instead of checking for the value TRUE I tried to use the isChecked() function and it works.

```
 function onEdit(e){
   if(e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value == "FALSE") return;
   for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
     if(i == e.range.rowStart) continue;
     if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1).isChecked() == true){
       e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1).setValue("FALSE");
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Congrats. But I suspect this implementation is quite slow. 300 calls to the server! Probably you can do it with just two calls. Which would be about 150 times faster

Comment: The `e.range` only specify the script to run only when the edit happens in the first column. The `for` makes it check the first 100 cells in column since the `getRange(i, 1)` is hardcoded to first column. So unless I have completely misunderstood, the code only runs in the first column and not the whole sheet. I do agree with Yuri though that it might not be very time effective and definitely can be optimized. But it works for now since I needed it to work on multiple sheets with checkboxes in different cells.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bit faster this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() != "Your Sheetname" || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value == "FALSE") return;
  let vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues()
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {if (i + 1 != e.range.rowStart) { vs[i][0] = "FALSE" }});
  sh.getRange(1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

If you your using its in a bunch of sheets, you could use:

```
if(!~['Sheet1','Sheet2].indexOf(sh.getName()) || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value == "FALSE") return;
```